# how to i show grouped fields in apache solr's jquery?

Tags: jquery, solr

i got some issues to show grouped fields in my apache solr project. i want to show grouped fields in autocomplete search but i didnt do it. it comes like 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fbuo.png) and i want to group them the query gives me correct results in web browser but i dont know how i show them in autocomplete jquery

here is my jquery code

```
<script>
$(function() {
var URL_PREFIX = "http://localhost:8983/solr/archiveCore/select?q=PackName:";
var URL_SUFFIX = "&wt=json&rows=0&indent=true&facet=true&facet.field=PackName";
$("#searchBoxPackName").autocomplete({
source : function(request, response) {
var URL = URL_PREFIX + $("#searchBoxPackName").val() + URL_SUFFIX;
$.ajax({
url : URL,
success : function(data) {
var docs = JSON.stringify(data.response.docs);
var jsonData = JSON.parse(docs);
response($.map(jsonData, function(value, key) {
return {
label : value.PackName
}
}));
},
dataType : 'jsonp',
jsonp : 'json.wrf'
});
},
minLength : 1
})
});
$(function() {
var URL_PREFIX = "http://localhost:8983/solr/archiveCore/select?q=PackName:";
var URL_MIDDLE = "OR PackName_ngram:";
var URL_SUFFIX = "&wt=json";
$("#ngramBoxPackName").autocomplete(
{
source :function(request, response) {
var searchString = "\"" + $("#ngramBoxPackName").val() + "\"";
var URL = URL_PREFIX + searchString + URL_MIDDLE
+ searchString + URL_SUFFIX;
$.ajax({
url : URL,
success : function(data) {
var docs = JSON.stringify(data.response.docs);
var jsonData = JSON.parse(docs);
response($.map(jsonData, function(value, key) {
return {
label : value.PackName
}
}));
},
dataType : 'jsonp',
jsonp : 'json.wrf'
});
},
minLength : 1
})
});
</script>
```

is there any way to show them my autocomplete project??

Comment: If you're going to use faceting, you'll have to use the result returned from the `.facet` element and not the `docs` element. It's very hard to tell from your code what you're actually displaying (if anything), and the lack of indentation makes it hard to read.

Comment: @MatsLindh i decided to not use faceting but i want to use grouping. is there any idea for this?

Comment: Your example shows something else. Make sure you're including the code that's relevant to your actual question. The comment is still true - it's impossible to say without knowing what you're displaying.

Comment: @MatsLindh i changed the query like this `http://localhost:8983/solr/archiveCore/select?group.field=PackName&group=true&q=PackName%3A*&rows=2147483647&start=0&wt=json&indent=true&fl=PackName_ngram` and it gives me what i want but i dont now how i show them in autocomplete ngram and i am displaying my documents package names but there are too many same package names and i want to grouping them